# Retrieveing 50 search results from Google search engine using Python and JSON

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, search-engine, google-search

I have been using this simple Python code to write a simple program, the only problem is that it only returns the top 3 search results. I am looking for a method where I can retrieve at least 50 top search results from the Google search engine.

```
import urllib
import json

exampleSearch = 'pagerank'
encoded = urllib.quote(exampleSearch)

rawData = urllib.urlopen('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q='+encoded).read()

jsonData = json.loads(rawData)
searchResults = jsonData['responseData']['results']


for er in searchResults:
    title = er['title']
    link = er['url']
    print title 
    print link
    print '''

            '''
```

P.S: I do not own the paid version of GoogleSiteSearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using the deprecated search API.  You need to use the custom search API and pass an API token:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest

How to get your own API token:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/introduction#identify_your_application_to_google_with_api_key